# building webkit on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webkit, windows-store-apps

I have some html containing WEBKIT content which needs to be rendered on Windows Phone 8 browser and Windows 8 Store apps webview. As windows 8 and wp8 browser control doesn't support webkit.

is there any way where:

1. I can map webkit to IE specific tags internally in code and then calling Webview.NavigateToString(html).
2. As Webkit is Open source, Can I build webkit to dll and use it as a control in my WP8/W8 to render Webkit html?

If there is any better way other than this, please suggest...
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "Webkit content" exactly? HTML, CSS, JS? Can you show some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

By webkit "content" and "specific tags" I'm assuming that you're referring to `-webkit` specific prefixes in the CSS.

1. There is no way to map these to anything that can be automatically converted to the IE specific equivalent.
2. Building your own browser (which is essentially what you'd be doing if you got the webkit code compiling for the phone) is likely to be masses of work. Much more than modifying the code you are displaying.

The best approach is to simply include the IE equivalent version of the vendor specific extension where one exists. This is the same as you would do if you had content that you wanted to take advantage of such extensions and run on multiple browsers. (i.e. Firefox and Opera also.)

You should also seriously consider if you need things to look identical on multiple devices. (Hint. you don't.) Your time may be better served by ensuring you are displaying content which looks appropriate on the appropriate device, rather than trying to use the code for getting something to display in a specific way on one device/browser to work on another.